# Putting text in the middle of a run-off triangle (table)

Tags: tables

Consider the MWE below, giving the following figure:

[image]

Now I want to adjust my code such that in the middle of the table the same text appears as in the following figure. What is the best way to do it, without altering the shape of the triangle?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Run-off triangle}
\begin{tabular}{l|llllllllll}
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Accident year i/\\ Development year     j\end{tabular}} & \textbf{1}            & \textbf{2}            & \textbf{3}              & \textbf{...}          & \textbf{...}          & \textbf{...}          &      \textbf{j}            & \textbf{...}          & \textbf{...}          & \textbf{J}            \\ \hline
\textbf{1}                                                                                 &                       &                       &                       &                           &                       &                       &                       &                      &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{11-11} 
\textbf{2}                                                                                  &                       &                       &                       &                        &                       &                       &                       &                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       \\ \cline{10-10}
\textbf{\vdots}                                                                           &                       &                       &                       &                        &                       &                       &                       &    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       \\     \cline{9-9}
\textbf{\vdots}                                                                        &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                        &                       &                       \\ \cline{8-8}
\textbf{i}                                                                             &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       \\ \cline{7-7}
\textbf{\vdots}                                                                        &                       &                       &                       &                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\ \cline{6-6}
\textbf{\vdots}                                                                        &                       &                       &                       &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\   \cline{5-5}
\textbf{\vdots}                                                                           &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\ \cline{4-4}
\textbf{I-1}                                                                           &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\ \cline{3-3}
\textbf{I}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       &                       \\ \cline{2-2}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What a complicated way to draw that figure. It would be better to use Tikz instead of table to draw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\llap{Observations $C_{ij},X_{ij}$}
```

in a specific cell to insert the text. you just need to discover which one!

Since your code is too complicated, you can count lines and columns to determine it.

I inserted it in line 2 and the other in line 3, just below.

[image]

```
\textbf{2}  & & & & & & & \llap{Observations $C_{ij},X_{ij}$} 
      & & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \\ \cline{10-10}
\textbf{\vdots}  & & & & & & & \llap{$(i+j\leq 1)$} 
        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & & \\ \cline{9-9}
```

**Edit:** I'd also use `$\mathbf{i}$` and so on for math contents.