# Drawing lines between cells in tabular environments

Tags: tables

I have a tabular environment, and what I want to do is to draw a path \emph{between} cells in that environment.  Essentially, I want to show partitions of a matrix.

The table I have is as follows:

```
\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c}
& \textbf{$a_1$} & \textbf{$a_2$} & \textbf{$a_3$} & \textbf{$a_4$} & \textbf{$a_5$} & \textbf{$a_6$} \\
\hline
\textbf{$b_1$} & $a_1 b_1$ & $a_2 b_1$ & $a_3 b_1$ & $a_4 b_1$ & $a_5 b_1$ & $a_6 b_1$ \\
\textbf{$b_2$} & $a_1 b_2$ & $a_2 b_2$ & $a_3 b_2$ & $a_4 b_2$ & $a_5 b_2$ & $a_6 b_2$ \\
\textbf{$b_3$} & $a_1 b_3$ & $a_2 b_3$ & $a_3 b_3$ & $a_4 b_3$ & $a_5 b_3$ & $a_6 b_3$ \\
\textbf{$b_4$} & $a_1 b_4$ & $a_2 b_4$ & $a_3 b_4$ & $a_4 b_4$ & $a_5 b_4$ & $a_6 b_4$ \\
\textbf{$b_5$} & $a_1 b_5$ & $a_2 b_5$ & $a_3 b_5$ & $a_4 b_5$ & $a_5 b_5$ & $a_6 b_5$ \\
\textbf{$b_6$} & $a_1 b_6$ & $a_2 b_6$ & $a_3 b_6$ & $a_4 b_6$ & $a_5 b_6$ & $a_6 b_6$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

That displays like this:
[image: Image of a table of multiplied values]

What I want to do is to draw lines that partition this table.  For instance, I may want to draw a path that goes in a diagonal-ish pattern.  That would have a line to the right of a4b1, under a4b1, to the right of a3b2, under a3b2, to the right of a2b3, under a2b3, to the right of a1b4, and under a1b4.

How might this be accomplished?  Additionally, might there be some way to make some lines dashed, dotted, etc.?  That's not critical, but it would be nice.

Comment: Something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/419499/2388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some possibilities:

[image]

In order to position the short horizontal and vertical rules, I have used `\cline` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}`. I have also increased the height of the rows using `\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}`.

In order to achieve dashed lines, I have used the `arydshln` package in combination with `\cdashline` and `\multicolumn{1}{c:}`

As all contents of your table are in math mode, and not affected by `\textbf`, you might alos consider using an `array` environment instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bm}
  \begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c}
& $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ \\
\hline
$b_1$ & $a_1 b_1$ & $a_2 b_1$ & $a_3 b_1$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{$a_4 b_1$} & $a_5 b_1$ & $a_6 b_1$ \\ \cline{5-5}
$b_2$ & $a_1 b_2$ & $a_2 b_2$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{$a_3 b_2$} & $a_4 b_2$ & $a_5 b_2$ & $a_6 b_2$ \\
\cline{4-4}
$b_3$ & $a_1 b_3$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{$a_2 b_3$} & $a_3 b_3$ & $a_4 b_3$ & $a_5 b_3$ & $a_6 b_3$ \\
\cline{3-3}
$b_4$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{$a_1 b_4$} & $a_2 b_4$ & $a_3 b_4$ & $a_4 b_4$ & $a_5 b_4$ & $a_6 b_4$ \\
\cline{2-2}
$b_5$ & $a_1 b_5$ & $a_2 b_5$ & $a_3 b_5$ & $a_4 b_5$ & $a_5 b_5$ & $a_6 b_5$ \\
$b_6$ & $a_1 b_6$ & $a_2 b_6$ & $a_3 b_6$ & $a_4 b_6$ & $a_5 b_6$ & $a_6 b_6$ \\
\end{tabular}



\setlength\dashlinegap{0.75pt}

\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c}
& $a_1$ & $a_2$ & $a_3$ & $a_4$ & $a_5$ & $a_6$ \\
\hline
$b_1$ & $a_1 b_1$ & $a_2 b_1$ & $a_3 b_1$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c:}{$a_4 b_1$} & $a_5 b_1$ & $a_6 b_1$ \\ \cdashline{5-5}
$b_2$ & $a_1 b_2$ & $a_2 b_2$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c:}{$a_3 b_2$} & $a_4 b_2$ & $a_5 b_2$ & $a_6 b_2$ \\
\cdashline{4-4}
$b_3$ & $a_1 b_3$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c:}{$a_2 b_3$} & $a_3 b_3$ & $a_4 b_3$ & $a_5 b_3$ & $a_6 b_3$ \\
\cdashline{3-3}
$b_4$ & \multicolumn{1}{ c:}{$a_1 b_4$} & $a_2 b_4$ & $a_3 b_4$ & $a_4 b_4$ & $a_5 b_4$ & $a_6 b_4$ \\
\cdashline{2-2}
$b_5$ & $a_1 b_5$ & $a_2 b_5$ & $a_3 b_5$ & $a_4 b_5$ & $a_5 b_5$ & $a_6 b_5$ \\
$b_6$ & $a_1 b_6$ & $a_2 b_6$ & $a_3 b_6$ & $a_4 b_6$ & $a_5 b_6$ & $a_6 b_6$ \\
\end{tabular}


\[
\begin{array}{c | c c c c c c}
&  \bm{a_1}  &  \bm{a_2}  &  \bm{a_3}  &  \bm{a_4}  &  \bm{a_5}  & \bm{a_6}  \\
\hline
\bm{b_1}  &  a_1 b_1  &  a_2 b_1  &  a_3 b_1  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ a_4 b_1 } &  a_5 b_1  &  a_6 b_1  \\ \cline{5-5}
 \bm{b_2}  &  a_1 b_2  &  a_2 b_2  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ a_3 b_2 } &  a_4 b_2  &  a_5 b_2  &  a_6 b_2  \\
\cline{4-4}
\bm{b_3} &  a_1 b_3  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ a_2 b_3 } &  a_3 b_3  &  a_4 b_3  &  a_5 b_3  &  a_6 b_3  \\
\cline{3-3}
 \bm{b_4} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ a_1 b_4 } &  a_2 b_4  &  a_3 b_4  &  a_4 b_4  &  a_5 b_4  &  a_6 b_4  \\
\cline{2-2}
\bm{ b_5 } &  a_1 b_5  &  a_2 b_5  &  a_3 b_5  &  a_4 b_5  &  a_5 b_5  &  a_6 b_5  \\
\bm{b_6} &  a_1 b_6  &  a_2 b_6  &  a_3 b_6  &  a_4 b_6  &  a_5 b_6  &  a_6 b_6  \\
\end{array}
\]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabular}` (of the package `array`) but creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns. Then, it's possible to use Tikz to draw whatever rule you want with these nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c | c c c c c c}
        & $a_1$     & $a_2$    & $a_3$     & $a_4$     & $a_5$     & $a_6$ \\
  \hline
  $b_1$ & $a_1 b_1$ & $a_2 b_1$ & $a_3 b_1$ & $a_4 b_1$ & $a_5 b_1$ & $a_6 b_1$ \\
  $b_2$ & $a_1 b_2$ & $a_2 b_2$ & $a_3 b_2$ & $a_4 b_2$ & $a_5 b_2$ & $a_6 b_2$ \\
  $b_3$ & $a_1 b_3$ & $a_2 b_3$ & $a_3 b_3$ & $a_4 b_3$ & $a_5 b_3$ & $a_6 b_3$ \\
  $b_4$ & $a_1 b_4$ & $a_2 b_4$ & $a_3 b_4$ & $a_4 b_4$ & $a_5 b_4$ & $a_6 b_4$ \\
  $b_5$ & $a_1 b_5$ & $a_2 b_5$ & $a_3 b_5$ & $a_4 b_5$ & $a_5 b_5$ & $a_6 b_5$ \\
  $b_6$ & $a_1 b_6$ & $a_2 b_6$ & $a_3 b_6$ & $a_4 b_6$ & $a_5 b_6$ & $a_6 b_6$ \\
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (6-|2) -| (5-|3) -| (4-|4) -| (3-|5) -| (2-|6) ; 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a combination of multicolumn and cline.
It's cumbersome to explain. Why not using

https://tablesgenerator.com/

to create your table?